# How to add extra data to tag

Tags: ruby, xml, rss

Ruby. I use standart builder to generate rss. My builder file is:

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0"
xml.rss(:version => "2.0") {
xml.channel {
    xml.title(@digest.name)
    xml.description(@digest.name)
    xml.link(url_for(:only_path => false))
    for post in @posts
        xml.item do
            xml.title(post.title || '')
            xml.description(post.summary)
            xml.link(post.url)
            xml.source(post.feed.name)
            xml.guid(post.url)
            xml.pubDate(post.pub_date.to_s(:rfc822))
        end
     end
    }
}
```

To generate an rss feed(`require rss`) I use next code :

```
xml.source(post.feed.name)
```

and get:

```
<source>Cnn news</source>
```

But I want something like that:

```
<source url="http://news.cnn.com">Cnn news</source>
```

How can I add parameter `url` to xml source tag?

Comment: What library are you using? Builder, or something else? Also, with what specification do you wish to be compliant? RSS 2.0?

Comment: Where do you get your xml object from?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to point that I use builder and want RSS 2.0

Comment: @Sunny Juneja, I create my xml object from parsed data from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what library you're using to do this but if you pass a hash to builder it'll just add that as attributes of the node.

```
require 'builder'
 => true 
x = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => $stdout, :indent => 1)
<inspect/>
 => #<IO:0x000000008822a0> 
x.source("CNN News", "url" => "http://www.cnn.com")
<source url="http://www.cnn.com">CNN News</source>
 => #<IO:<STDOUT>>
```

Comment: Sunny Juneja, thanks. It's quite that I need: `x.source("CNN News", "url" => "http://www.cnn.com")`